# Including % symbol in table caption of bookdown latex table

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, kable

I am having trouble including the '%' symbol in the caption of a table produced by the `knitr::kable` function in a `bookdown` Rmarkdown document. For example, the following code:

````
---
title: "Test of table caption with percent symbol"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
df = data.frame(id=1:3,names=letters[1:3])

knitr::kable(df,caption="This captions has a % symbol",booktabs=TRUE)
```
````

produces the following:

[image]

However, if I remove the '%' symbol from the caption or I use `pdf_document` instead of `bookdown::pdf_document2` then the output is formatted correctly.

What is the best solution to be able to include '%' and other symbols special to LaTeX in the figure caption? Also, I need a solution that works for multiple output formats (e.g., DOC and HTML in addition to PDF).

Answer (score 3):

I found two solutions to my own question. One is to use a caption reference:

````
---
title: "Test of table caption with percent symbol"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  pdf_document: default
---

(ref:mycap) This captions has a % symbol

```{r}
df = data.frame(id=1:3,names=letters[1:3])

knitr::kable(df,caption="(ref:mycap)",booktabs=TRUE)
```
````

The other is to set `format="pandoc"` in `knitr::kable`:

````
---
title: "Test of table caption with percent symbol"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
df = data.frame(id=1:3,names=letters[1:3])

knitr::kable(df,caption="This captions has a % symbol",booktabs=TRUE,format="pandoc")
```
````

These solutions produce somewhat different table placements on the page and the caption reference solution will not work if one switches from `bookdown::pdf_document2` to `pdf_document`, but otherwise the output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only thing that worked with `format=latex` was this:

```
knitr::kable(df,
caption='This and that with 1\\char"25\\:of total.', format = "latex")
```

[image: output]

Explanation:

- Internally, the `%` symbol is `\char"25`.
- bookdown will first generate a .tex file, so you need to add a `\` in front of `\char"25` in order to escape it.
- This "eats" the space following the `%`. So I added a space (`\:`), but of course escaped too (`\\:`)